# How many samples to state $P(A < B) \ge 95\%, A, B \sim \text{Bernoulli}$?

Tags: confidence-interval, inference, bernoulli-distribution, bernoulli-process

Suppose I have two series of samples:

$$A \sim Be(p)$$

$$B \sim Be(q)$$

How may samples samples do I need to state that:
$$P(A<B) \ge 95\%$$

Comment: Your question is unclear.  A and B are draws from a bernoulli distribution.  Do you mean to ask about the bias parameters p and q?  Either A will be less than B or not.

Comment: @DemetriPananos thanks for helping me improve the question. I have two random variables A and B that are Bernoulli distributed, with different $p_A$ and $p_B$.  As I collect samples of A and B I estimate $p_A$ and $p_B$. Based on the estimates it seems $p_A < p_B$, but the estimates fluctuate. So I want to know how many samples I need to collect to state that $P(p_A > p_B)= 95\%$. Is this equivalent to the question above as edited by @AdamO?

Comment: @elemolotiv your previous question was unclear. You said $P(p < q) = .95$ without stating the prior or the decision framework. I think you accidentally deBayesd yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If $A,B$ independent:

$P(A < B)  = P(B=1|A=0) \times P(A=0) = p (1-q) = \widetilde{p}$

In fact, the event: $B=1, A=0$ is a whole new Bernoulli process $C$ with probability $\widetilde{p}$.

If you want to test the null hypothesis that $\widetilde{p} \le 0.95$ then you have to perform a somewhat standard power/sample size calculation. For instance, if $\widetilde{p}$ is actually 0.975, then the standard large sample binomial test with 80% power at the 0.05 one-sided level requires 384 samples of A, B.